Using 5-in-1 dimmable power supply with PWM dimmer for LED strip
I hope my question is not too basic. I'm confused as to how I am supposed to connect a PWM 24V dimmer with my 24V 5-in-1 dimmable power supply.
The 5-in-1 has AC inputs (neutral and load), LED- and LED+, and DIM- and DIM+, while my PWM dimmer has Input-, Input+, Output- and Output+.
The diagram of the 5-in-1 power supply is like this:
The dimmer is like this:

Update: I didn't notice a piece of paper in the box, the diagram is different but still doesn't make sense to me, as it says to plug the DC dimmer on AC current...


Where is the datasheet for the power supply?

I added a link to the exact power supply I have.

you can just ignore the dimming feature of the driver and connect the PWM dimmer in series with the output of the driver, if you want to use that knob/product for reasons.

The first product is an AC powered dimmer (essentially a dimmer combined with a power supply), the second is a DC powered dimmer (same as the first but minus the power supply). Normally you would use one or the other depending on if you needed the AC input or not.
Since he AC dimmer can take a PWM signal as an input, you could probably get a second power supply, power up the DC dimmer and then use that as an input to the AC dimmer. However, it would be much easier to buy a normal 0-10v dimmer control knob or even a triac dimmer if you find control from the AC side easier.


Update: I didn't notice a piece of paper in the box, the diagram is
different but still doesn't make sense to me, as it says to plug the
DC dimmer on AC current...


A TRIAC dimmer is an AC dimmer, and the most common type on light switches.  You'd have to buy one of those if you wanted to use TRIAC dimming.

Thank you. I was referring to the second diagram which seemed to use yet another type of AC powered dimmer.

The datasheet shows a line-connected PWM module to the control input of the power supply; the one you have is not compatible. A bare potentiometer is probably easier and definitely cheaper than buying a new PWM module; the end result is the same.
